# Why do we use STUN servers?

Tags: webrtc

If stun servers give the browser the public IP for the clients, why couldn't the signaling server give us this as well?

Or is there something else that I am missing

I was reading this here: https://bloggeek.me/google-free-turn-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP and TCP might be routed differently, in particular when there is a HTTP proxy.

Also, a signaling server will know *some* address of the client, but it will not know a port that going to result in a connection as one needs UDP holepunching for that.